# Match within a match?

Tags: f#

Is there a way to do a match within a match in F#? I've noticed that you can do one tailed on another like so...

```
match L.Head with
| null -> []
| _ -> match N with
| 1 -> [L.Head]
| _ -> []
```

But is there a way to do it so that a match, ending with a _ can be placed in the MIDDLE of another match? This seems to give a bug... is there a better way to do this, should you need it for your logic? EX:

```
match A with
| 0 -> match B with
       | 1 -> 1
       | _ -> 0
| _ -> 2
```

Comment: Your second example seems to work fine.  What seems to be your problem?

Comment: @mydogisbox does it? For me, it sees the '_' in match B with, and ends all matching.

Comment: I wrapped it in a function and passed `1` for `A` and `0` for `B` and got `2`.  That's how it's supposed to work.  Were you expecting something different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use match on a tuple -

```
match (A,B) with
|0,1 -> 1
|0,_ -> 0
|_,  -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it was possible 7 years ago, but now you can use `struct` to reduce allocations:

```ml
match struct (A, B) with
| 0, 1 -> 1
| 0, _ -> 0
| _    -> 2
```

Old answer creates instance of `` System.Tuple`2 ``, while this creates instance of `` System.ValueTuple`2 ``
[Decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AbEAzAzgHwFgAoDGAFwAIBzCgNQEMMBXGSgCgEpKBeSgZQCeucjAC2AOgBKDAHYATCGK4SAcjATkuJEmSoM0lYLxr0mrDp0O1yjFjG3ESYhuTAALSgaOUA7gEtydxJ8SgBGQwAmSjgAPkoAByh/WXJsWUoAIjDKSMyQygBmQxQY+KSUtIzMwsoUfOJQhENBMsTk1PTKABJMgFJ5AG8EAF9KAcHBEYaSCs7quEWl5ZXlmeIXN08RKGYwKnZvYG4AoIKI3La5qqycvILiuquOm5q6hqaW58qu3onR8ZDKYNIA===)